# UITableViewCell text shrinking on DispatchQueue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a label in my TableViewCell. Whenever I dequeue the cell, with DispatchQueue the label in the cell is shrunk. On the contrary, When I simply dequeue it, The label changes to normal. 
What could be the possible reason and fix for this?

Before DispatchQueue
[image]

After DispatchQueue
[image]

The codes :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FeedCell") as? FeedCell {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            cell.configureCell(post: post)
        }
        return cell
    } else {
        return FeedCell()
    }
}
```

Code for Label Layouts in FeedCell(UITableViewCell):

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.caption.sizeToFit()
}
```

`contentView` is the UIView in which the Label rests.

Comment: Why are you dispatching the comfiguration onto the main queue?  That code is already running on the main queue. The answer to your question is that the configuration happens after you have already returned the cell to the tableview, so it has already been sized to fit an empty caption

Comment: Yes. It is true that UI updates need to be performed in the main queue, but methods like this, which are called by UI elements will already be on the main queue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to dispatch that function onto the main queue, as `cellForRowAt:` will always be called on the main queue.

Since you are dispatching your `configureCell` call asynchronously you end up returning an unconfigured cell from `cellForRowAt:`, which causes `self.caption.sizeToFit()` to be called for an empty caption (or if the cell is subsequently reused, it would be sized for whatever caption was previously in that cell object).

You could ensure that `configureCell` triggers a cell relayout, but it is simpler to just remove the unnecessary `DispatchQueue.main.async`